# What is the correct numba decorator to return an array of different size than the parameter passed?

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

I want to use numba to vectorize a function to count the occurrences of unique values.
The function receives a numpy array of any length, and returns a numpy array of length 257.

But I do  not understand how to specify the decorator. It doesn't' even compile.
I read the documentation [here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html#the-vectorize-decorator), but i get empty handed. It says nothing about different array sizes.

```
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.uint8[:], nb.uint64[:])], "(n) -> (m)", target="parallel")
def count_occurrences(byte_view):
    """
    Counts the occurrences of each element in a byte array and returns a new array with the counts.
    """
    # adds a zero to the beginning of the array, for convenience
    count = np.zeros(1 + 256, dtype=np.uint64)
    count[1 + byte_view] += 1
    return count


sample = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100, dtype=np.uint8)
counts = count_occurrences(sample)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are 1D arrays, there isn't anything that can be done in parallel with this setup. And then there doesn't seem to be much benefit of using `guvectorize` over `njit` in this case. Especially because `njit` would allow returning an array with a different shape than any of the inputs.

It's not possible to return an array of unknown shape with `guvectorize`, so you'll have to provide that as an input argument as well. And you should never return anything explicitly from a `guvectorize` function to begin with. That might be more intuitive if you consider that Numba (ideally) would parallelize the execution of the function you provide, meaning that in this case `count` would be initialized multiple times instead of only once (upfront).

It's not clear what the indexing with `byte_view` means in this context, if it contains the indices that need to be indexed, you can just loop over them as shown below.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize("void(uint8[:], uint64[:])", "(n),(m)", target="cpu")
def count_occurrences(byte_view, count):
    """
    Counts the occurrences of each element in a byte array and returns a new array with the counts.
    """
    for idx in byte_view: 
        count[1 + idx] += 1


sample = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100, dtype=np.uint8)

# adds a zero to the beginning of the array, for convenience
counts = np.zeros(1 + 256, dtype=np.uint64)

count_occurrences(sample, counts)
```

The snippet above makes it work, but as said, it doesn't add much over `njit`, and doesn't utilize what `guvectorize` normally adds over `njit`.

Comment: For OP: one could use parallelization on higher level, by passing parts of 1D array and sum results